# VZ Buyers for Expresso Store 2.0?

Tags: expresso-store, vz-buyers

The VZ Buyers plug in does not work for Store 2.0 and above and I was wondering if anyone had tinkered with it to get it to work?  Please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

The update to Store 2.x changed some of the extension hooks that [VZ Buyers](http://dvt.ee/adqj5ZC) used, the add-on will need to be modified to work with Store 2.0. Your best bet would be to ask the developer directly by going to the [Official Support Forum](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/vz-buyers/viewforum/1921) to see if there are plans to update it support Store 2.x.